# How do I use Javascript to auto resize the height of my Facebook tab?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, tabs

I am trying to create a simple HTML Facebook tab for my page, but I can't seem to find a fix for how to change the max height of the tab.

I should mention that I'm a beginner in coding, I know very basic HTML, but I've tried to avoid JavaScript since I have no experience with that whatsoever.

Unfortunately it seems like I can't do this without JavaScript, so my problem is most likely me doing something wrong.

The code looks something like this (the rest of the codes, including closing HTML-tags comes after the JavaScript part, and is working fine).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '***********', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//**********', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional initialization code here
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
</script>
```

I've pretty much copied the Javascript SDK from Facebook's developer pages and then found a small piece of code that should automatically set the height. I've googled for answers, but haven't been able to find anything that could fix this (or explain it in a way that an absolute newbie like me would understand).

Hope you can help me out.

//Frederik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since You mentioned you know very basic html I assume you are not aware of the CSS possibilities as well, so I suggest you to replace this:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
```

with this:

```
<div id="fb-root" style="max-width: 100px;"></div>
```

Comment: That was almost too simple - fixed it for me :)
Thank you very much, I've spent hours trying to work this out.

Answer (score 2):

Move this code `FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();` inside `fbAsyncInit` function, Example:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '***********', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//**********', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
 };
```

If you want to set the size manually, you could do by using `FB.Canvas.setSize()` function:

```
FB.Canvas.setSize({height: 800});
```

Change the above number `800` to whatever size you want it to increase.